# Formtastic - Creating a nested select from two objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, formtastic

I want to create a nested multi select in formtastic from two objects like this -

```
Option 1
   Option A
   Option B
   Option C
Option 2
   Option A
   Option B
   Option C

list1 = ['option1', 'option2']
list2 = ['Option A', 'Option B', 'Option C']
```

Is this possible with formtastic or is it better to use a helper to format the data ?

Thanks, Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, you have to use something like:

`<%= f.input :input_field_name, :as => :select, :collection => grouped_options_for_select(['List 1', list1], ['List 2', list2]) %>`

Look up the Formtastic documentation for `input_select` and the Rails API for `grouped_options_for_select` for other possible formatting options.

Comment: Thanks, this article helped as well - http://andrewradev.com/2011/05/25/grouped-select-helper-methods-in-rails/